# Check if dictionary exist within dictionary and if so change it

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary

I currently have an Ordered Dictionary named "modules_dict". Within "modules_dict" there are objects with class "module_class", and each of these objects could have instances of "submods" which are also class "module_class", so on and so forth.

My problem is: How do I check every single "module_class" and any of their "submods" if say a class "module_class" with name "digital" exist, if so replace it?

```
class module_class:
self.name
self.submods = OrderedDict()
```

Example:

```
modules_dict = {
"angel": module_class(submods = { 
    "analog": module_class(submods = { 
        "digital": module_class()})
    })
}
```

Non-ideal solution ("self" below represents the module_class "digital"):

```
for mod in modules_dict.values():
    for submod in mod.submods.values():
        for sub in submod:
            if self.name == sub.name:
                modules_dict[mod.name].submods[sub.name] = [self]

            for sm in sub.submods.values():
                for s in sm:
                    if self.name == s.name:
                        modules_dict[mod.name].submods[sub.name].submods[s.name] = [self]
```

Clearly there is no knowing of how many for-loops are required. I was thinking of using recursive, but I have no idea how to change the dictionary "modules_dict"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is definitely the way to go, especially since you're not sure how many nested dicts you could be dealing with.

I tried the other answer, but I had trouble getting it to work. I just successfully tested this:

```
def find_and_replace(d, key, replacement="replacement"):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print "found nested dict"
            if find_and_replace(v, key):
                return True

        elif isinstance(v, str):
            if k==key:
                d.update({k:replacement})
                print "replaced [%s] with [%s]" % (v, replacement)
                return True
```

Here's my output:

```
>>> etc = {'this': {'that': {'theother': 'a'}}}
>>> find_and_replace(etc, "theother")
found nested dict
found nested dict
replaced [a] with [replacement]
>>> print etc
{'this': {'that': {'theother': 'replacement'}}}
```

The `elif isinstance(v, str):` condition is a placeholder for you to implement your check for a `module` instance. Here I'm checking for strings, but you get the idea.

---

EDIT: 
Could the class from the problem statement be implemented like this?

```
import collections
class module_class(object):
    def __init__(self, submods={}):
        self.name = "name"
        self.submods = collections.OrderedDict(submods)
```

Comment: I think you got it confused. "modules" is a dictionary, while "module" is a class. So: module(submods = { "digital": module() }) means class module has an instance of submods, and submods is a dictionary like "modules"

Comment: I may have, but I think the logic to your solution is here. Check my use of http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update with `d.update({k:replacement})`

Comment: Yes that is pretty much the class. I am still trying to mess around the code